# How can I tell Simplecov to focus on specific directories in a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, simplecov

The title mostly speaks for itself.  To be more specific, it would seem to make sense to me that Simplecov be configured to only focus on directories like the app directory instead of including all of the configuration files and such that are going to be covered no matter what and are left unchanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your Simplecov config

```
SimpleCov.start do
 add_filter "/folder you don't want covered/"
end
```

A default filter automatically keeps Simplecov in your app/ directory.

See the docs for filters [here](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#filters)